# Showing variance of a cauchy r.v is not defined

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$ is r.v Cauchy with density $f(x) = \frac{1}{\pi (1 + (x - \alpha)^2 ) } $. Then $\sigma^2(X) $ is not defined and $\mathbb{E} \{ X^2 \} = \infty $

#### TRY:

I know $\sigma^2(X) = \mathbb{E} \{ X^2 \} - \mathbb{E} \{X\} ^2 $, so it would be enough to show $\mathbb{E} \{ X^2 \} = \infty $.

$$ \mathbb{E} \{ X^2 \} = \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} x f(x) dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{ x dx}{1 + (x - \alpha)^2} $$

Let $u = x - \alpha $ so $du = dx $ and we have

$$ \frac{1}{\pi}  \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{ u + \alpha }{ 1 + u^2 } du$$

But this integral goes to infinity, hence showing our claim. IS this correct?

Answer (score 0):

The mean doesn't exist for a Cauchy RV. Since existence of the $p>1$-th moment implies existence of the $q$-th moment for $1\leq q < p$, the non-existence of the mean implies the non-existence of the variance.

What you've actually done (by accident) is written out $E[X] = \int x f(x) dx$ (as what is marked  $E[X^2]$)and shown it doesn't exist, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using the wrong formula for the expectation, c.f. wiki:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

In fact

$$E(g(X)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)f(x) dx .$$

So in this case

$$E(X^2) =  \int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2 f(x) dx .$$

But clearly $x^2 f(x) \rightarrow \frac{1}{\pi} > 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ and as $x \rightarrow -\infty$. So the integral equals $\infty$.

You have also not really shown that the mean is undefined, should you wish to do so. In the Lebesgue sense,

$$ E(X) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x)$$

exists if and only if

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} |x| f(x) $$

is finite. The integrand $|x| f(x)$ is even, so it suffices to check that

$$\int_0^{\infty} x f(x) $$

is infinite. This is easy to do because there exists some $M>0$ and some $c>0$ such that $x f(x) \geq \frac{c}{x}$ for all $x>M$. And we know that

$$ \int_M^{\infty} \frac{c}{x} dx = \infty$$.

Comment: I have a couple of questions: is the last integral a Lebesgue one with $dx$as the Lebesgue measure? Why does exist some $M$ and $c$? I’m struggling to find references to do these calculations with Lebesgue integral. Thank you!